# How to trace/track my stolen Samsung Galaxy Ace 2

Tags: lost-phone, gps-tracking

Today was a bad day for me as I'm having a lot of problems. The latest and important event was I lost my phone. It was registered with my name and email and has information on it about me etc. The sim card is inside (if the robber didn't thrash it). The phone has gps but it's turned off. I hope I can find it.

If you have any question just ask me, maybe about the story how it began?
Is there any software/tools to track it, or find it manually maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to submit a request to Police Station to track your android device through its IMEI number. As soon as the mobile is switched on and it gets Signal from telecom company, its location will be detected.
Or alternatively, If you had any tracking app, installed on your device, then you may contact app developer for help to track your device.

Comment: is this things "ppl report to police n police track with IMEI" thing u said..rare or it was the often useed solution?

Comment: well! I have came accross this situation once. I lost my android device with No SIM CARD INSERTED in it. somebody got it and was using it . So this stuff helped me to get my device back... It is very oftenly used method but i will recommend you to search for someone who can track your device personally with IMEI because Police is so slow...

Comment: And that tracking is what the solutions in my answer provide, amongst other things. So if your device was stolen, I recommend going both ways in parallel -- but start with the solutions I mentioned as soon as possible: if the thief disables your account on the device (e.g. wipes it), they won't work anymore.

Comment: The thief would have been disabled all his account by now...

Comment: i think..naahhh..because i still can open the google play with my google account and the GP still can trace my phone with my google account..but idk if the sim was changed..it said Celcom and gt-18160(my sim celcom..but when i called always voice mail)..

Comment: I was saying that the Thief may probably have removed/changed your account from you device. -_-

Comment: can u use IMEI?

Comment: No! you need some specific machines to do so. That is why i am refering Police Station. They can track it easily if it is being used with any sim.

Comment: k ill try..
other way???

Comment: No! There is no other way to track the device.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you take a look at the [lost-phone tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info), which contains a lot of first-aid hints. As you write your SIM is still in the device, there's hope it's also still connected to your Google account and has a network connection -- so hurry up trying solutions like [Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) or [Android Lost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost), which you can then push to your device via Google Play's website. Find more details in the linked tag-wiki, plus on the apps' page at Google Play.

Comment: and if the sim was thrashed???cause i called always voice mail..yes it was my account in the phone..

Comment: As long as your account is still alive and connected on the device, mentioned solutions should work. They can't work obviously without a network connection. The SIM, on the other side, should be of not much interest to them (as long as a network connection is available, and your account still active on the device).

Comment: about the plan b..i ady installed it from pc..bu then it said step 2. Plan B will start automatically and send your phone’s location to your Gmail address. 3. To locate again after 10 minutes, borrow a friend’s phone and text the word “locate” to your lost phone...until now..i've done the text message..i sent locate(as there are no email from plan B in my gmail)..about 2 hours ady..

Comment: and the android lost..and still cant control...it said: 
Waiting for phone to be registered.
Register your phone by starting the application on your phone. If you have forgot your phone at home you may remotely start the app by sending an SMS with the text 'androidlost register' to your phone. Wait a little while. Please be patient. Relogin to this page to see if it has been registered..also 2 hours ady..

Comment: Sorry, I never used any of those solutions myself -- so I cannot say for sure; but to me that looks very much like there's no SIM card inserted anymore (so it cannot receive your SMS), and the device connected via WiFi, if at all (maybe not at all anymore, if there's no response). If I were the thief (beware!), the first thing to do would be switching off the device. And before switching it on again, remove the SIM so it doesn't connect to any network. Then, if I'm after the phone, wipe it, re-flash it. If I'm after your data, it's a different thing -- but for sure no network.

Comment: remote registration doesn't work on Android Lost - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/androidlost/Vo5_F0wF_do/0CUPZ5o2nuYJ